# `weighted.mean` in a function with an optional argument?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, mean, tidyeval

I need to include the `weighted.mean` function enclosed in another function as part of a project I'm working on. I'm having trouble getting the `w` argument to work correctly in the function I'm working on.

For my overall function to work properly I need to meet to make the weights argument needs to be optional. If there is no weights given I need to default to some kind of `wt = 1`. This is probably easy to do with a conditional statement where I make a dummy column filled with 1's but I am wondering if this is the best way.

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_weighted_mean <- function(var, wt) {
  var = enquo(var)
  
  mtcars %>%
    summarise_at(vars(!!var), ~weighted.mean(., w = wt))
  
}

## wrong output
my_weighted_mean(cyl, wt = "hp")
#>        cyl
#> 1 6.599231

## expected output
weighted.mean(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$hp)
#> [1] 6.860673
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Final update**

Making `wt` an optional argument (`wt = NULL`) was more complex than I anticipated. Below is an approach using `tryCatch`. Once we know whether `wt` is `NULL` we can replace it with a vector of `1` with the length of your `data.frame`. Otherwise, we can just use it with the curly-curly operator. Following the OP's comments the new function takes only one Argument `x` to summarise one variable and multiple grouping variables can be put into the ellipsis `...`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

my_weighted_mean <- function(.dat, x, ..., wt = NULL) {
  
  .pred <- tryCatch(
    is.null(wt),
    error = function(e) {
      is.null(rlang::eval_tidy(enquo(wt), data = mtcars))
    })
  
  .dat %>% 
    group_by(...) %>% 
    summarise(
      {{x}} := weighted.mean({{x}},
                             w = if (.pred) rep(1, length({{x}})) else {{wt}} ))
  
}

mtcars %>% 
  my_weighted_mean(mpg)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>     mpg
#>   <dbl>
#> 1  20.1

mtcars %>% 
  my_weighted_mean(mpg, cyl)
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl   mpg
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4  26.7
#> 2     6  19.7
#> 3     8  15.1

mtcars %>% 
  my_weighted_mean(mpg, cyl, wt = disp)
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl   mpg
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4  25.8
#> 2     6  19.8
#> 3     8  14.9

mtcars %>% 
  my_weighted_mean(mpg, cyl, gear, wt = disp)
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'cyl' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl  gear   mpg
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4     3  21.5
#> 2     4     4  25.9
#> 3     4     5  27.9
#> 4     6     3  19.9
#> 5     6     4  19.7
#> 6     6     5  19.7
#> 7     8     3  14.8
#> 8     8     5  15.4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**older answer**

You need to `enqou()` `wt` as well or just use the curly-curly operator. If you want to insert more than one variable into `var` then you can use the ellipsis `...` instead of the variable name wrapped into curly-curly.

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_weighted_mean <- function(var, wt) {
  
  mtcars %>%
    summarise_at(vars({{var}}), ~weighted.mean(., w = {{wt}}))
  
}

my_weighted_mean(cyl, wt = hp)
#>        cyl
#> 1 6.860673


my_weighted_mean <- function(..., wt) {

  mtcars %>%
    summarise_at(vars(...), ~weighted.mean(., w = {{wt}}))
  
}

my_weighted_mean(cyl, disp, wt = hp)
#>        cyl     disp
#> 1 6.860673 275.1096
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Fromer update of old answer (corrected)** As @Konrad Rudolph correctly points out, `summarise_at` is superseded and you don't need it for a single variable - here `summarise` is enough. If you want to summarise many variables, the new official way would be to use `across()` as follows:

```r
my_weighted_mean <- function(..., wt) {
  
  mtcars %>%
    summarise(across(c(...),
                     ~weighted.mean(., w = {{wt}})))
  
}

my_weighted_mean(cyl, disp, wt = hp)
```

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? Supoose mtcars is grouped `mtcars %>% group_by(disp) %>% summarise(`... how can I expand `wt` to support that?

Comment: Is the grouping variable given or is this also an optional argument to your function?

Comment: It's also an optional argument, I can change the question if helpful

Comment: I will have to come back to this tomorrow, but one last question: do you want to allow more than one grouping variable? Keep in mind that we can use the ellipsis `...` only once, either for multiple grouping variables or for multiple input variables to summarize.

Comment: The ellipsis should be used for the grouping variable. Thank you so much!

Comment: I updated my "final answer". Please check if it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

As Tim mentions, you need to handle `wt` in the same way as `var`, i.e. by passing it as an unquoted expression, and enquoting it inside the function.

Furthermore, since we’re already using tidy evaluation, there’s no need to for `summarize_at` (which is, incidentally, [superseded](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html)).

```
my_weighted_mean = function (.data, var, wt) {
    dplyr::summarize(.data, {{var}} := weighted.mean({{var}}, w = {{wt}}))
}
```

```
my_weighted_mean(mtcars, cyl, hp)
#        cyl
# 1 6.860673
```